# Quiero cambiar mi right y left de una clase css desde javascript y no puedo

Tags: javascript, css, html5, safari

Mi problema es el siguiente quiero cambiar el right y el left de un css desde un javascript pero desde una resolución 1920 aquí esta mi codigo.

```js
var es_safari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;
var mediaquery = window.matchMedia("(max-media: 1920px)")
if (es_safari) {
  if (mediaquery.matches) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.box-emergent-right').style.right = "38.100%";
    document.getElementsByClassName('.box-emergent').style.left = "38.100%";
  }
}
```

```css
.box-emergent {
  left: 20%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.box-emergent-right {
  right: 70%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Prueba javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box-emergent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea nam explicabo hic animi culpa debitis, odio ipsa excepturi quidem facilis, fugiat, cupiditate provident a porro. Ipsam, totam, obcaecati. Laudantium, quibusdam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-emergent-right">

  </div>


</body>
```

Primera Imagen de derecha bien renderizada desde chrome.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La Segunda Imagen podran notar que desde ipad no rederiza bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Explica mejor lo que intentas. Mira [ask] -Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

### Solución con CSS

Yo te recomiendo que, para evitarte el tener que hacer uso de Javascript, lo hagas directamente desde el CSS a través de los **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)**.

Ejemplo:

```css
.box-emergent {
  left: 20%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.box-emergent-right {
  right: 70%;
  background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .box-emergent-right{
      right: 38.100%;
  }
  
  .box-emergent{
    left: 38.100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Prueba javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box-emergent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea nam explicabo hic animi culpa debitis, odio ipsa excepturi quidem facilis, fugiat, cupiditate provident a porro. Ipsam, totam, obcaecati. Laudantium, quibusdam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-emergent-right">

  </div>


</body>
```

### Solución con Javascript

En caso de que lo quisieras hacer sí o sí desde Javascript he visto varios fallos en tu código:

- En tu función `matchMedia` tendrías que usar `max-width` en vez de `max-media`.
- Cuando utilizas la función `getElementsByClassName` no tienes que ponerle el punto a las clases, por lo que quedaría `document.getElementsByClassName('box-emergent')`.
- Por último, como la función `getElementsByClassName` devuelve un array y solamente tienes un elemento de cada, tendrás que hacer referencia a la primera posición (0) del array para recuperar el único elemento que se encuentra con esa clase. En caso contrario te devolverá `undefined` y te dará un error ya que no puedes cambiar las propiedades a un elemento que no existe.

  En caso de que tuvieras más de un elemento que quisieras cambiar tendrías que realizar un bucle que recorriera todo el array de elementos con la misma clase.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```js
var es_safari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;
var mediaquery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1920px)")
if (es_safari) {
  if (mediaquery.matches) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('box-emergent-right')[0].style.right = "38.100%";
    document.getElementsByClassName('box-emergent')[0].style.left = "38.100%";
  }
}
```

```css
.box-emergent {
  left: 20%;
  right: auto;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.box-emergent-right {
  right: 70%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Prueba javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box-emergent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea nam explicabo hic animi culpa debitis, odio ipsa excepturi quidem facilis, fugiat, cupiditate provident a porro. Ipsam, totam, obcaecati. Laudantium, quibusdam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-emergent-right">

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: ¿Me podrias podrías mostrar como hacer eso?, Es que soy novato en ello y necesito cambiar justamente unas imagenes de un proyecto desde un navegador safari por via javascript.

Comment: @Tysaic Te he dejado el código corregido en la respuesta, solo que lo he ocultado para no hacerla demasiado larga y que fuera difícil de leer. ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes al implementar los cambios?

Comment: Ese cambio ya lo he hecho el problema son mis navegadores, en chrome la plantilla se ve maravillosamente bien, pero en safari se descuadra completamente la imagen si Deseas te puedo pasar la pagina al privado para que veas como se ve en chrome y la diferencia en safari desde ipadpeek.com

Comment: @Tysaic ¿Ahora no te está detectando si estás utilizando Safari?

Comment: Si lo detecta el problema es que en chrome la imagen se ve como desea el cliente en cambio en safari se ve la imagen fuera de lugar así de simple.

Comment: @Tysaic ¿Podríamos ver el código que hace referencia a esa imagen? En este caso no has puesto ninguna imagen y es un poco difícil reproducir el error. Intenta hacer un ejemplo simple con una imagen y así te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: este es el enlace (www.archimorphic.com/about) de la pagina miralo desde la pagina de chrome y firefox, y luego desde www.ipadpeed.com. Son las imagenes de las personas del about cerca del footer. 

 Mil disculpas no se indexar imagenes aquí.

Comment: @Tysaic ¿Qué es lo que te aparece diferente? Yo me he metido en ambos navegadores y no veo diferencia en cuanto a las imágenes se refiere. Yo las veo igual en ambos navegadores. ¿Has probado a borrar la caché en tu navegador para que se actualicen los cambios?

Comment: Si lo he probado por que es un wordpress lo que pasa es que el safari es desde ipad por eso el renderizado es diferente de seguro lo ves por una Mac. Como podría pasarte una imagen por aquí? Allí podras ver la diferencia que las tengo aquí.

Comment: @Tysaic No dispongo de ningún Mac, lo estaba viendo en la página que me has pasado desde un ordenador Windows. Puedes añadir imágenes a la pregunta si le das a editar, justo encima del texto, hay unos iconos. Habrá uno con una montaña para poder agregar imágenes.

Comment: ya hice la edición por favor revisa las iamgenes que acabe de añadir.